# Are linear languages always unambiguous?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, ambiguity

Deterministic Context free languages are always unambiguous. Now DCFL are a subset of linear languages. Are there any linear languages which are inherently ambiguous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linear language $\{ a^ib^jc^k \mid i=j \text{ or } j=k\}$ is inherently ambiguous.

Comment: Question has a sentence saying "DCFL are a subset of linear languages." Is it correct? Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar#Relationship_with_regular_grammars): "linear languages that are regular languages are deterministic". And we know that there are DCFLs which are not regular. Hence, there must exists DCFLs which are not linear. Correct?

Comment: Good observation. There are indeed nonlinear DCFL. An example is the set of strings with matching parentheses.